# What would you call "razor blade"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, vocabulário

What would you call "razor blade" in Brazilian Portuguese?

[image]

suggestions: gilete, lâmina de navalha, lâmina de barbear

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking about the razor used to shave, you can say ***lâmina*** or ***lâmina de barbear***. See this picture:

[image]

**Gillette** is often used as a synonym for "*razor blade*" (at least in Brazil), although it is only a trademark (and not only sells razor blades).

Particularly I would translate for "***lâmina***" if you are referring only to the piece of metal, which can be part of other tools, like a stylus ("estilete" in portuguese), and "***lâmina de barbear***" when speaking about razor blade.

Comment: Same in Portugal.

Comment: É desta pergunta que falas? Então o autor não propõe sugestões?

Comment: @JorgeB leia novamente o comentário do meta...

Comment: Tem tempo para ir ao [chat] um minuto?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you use the razor blade for: shaving, lâmina is the term.
Like: a package of razor blades. Um pacote de lâminas. The formal term is lâmina de barbear.

navalha is a straight razor with a blade. the blade is also lâmina, but, de navalha.